# SIGABRT Error on renderCommandEncoder.drawPrimitives(...)

Tags: ios, metal

So I got a MTLRenderCommandEncoder that causes a crash when trying to .drawPrimitives(), it's a signal SIGABRT error, not shure how to debug this, any tips?

Comment: Well, the crash details, like the last bit of output in Xcode's console and the stack trace, would be helpful. `SIGABRT` is probably because the Metal validation layer has detected that you're doing something wrong. It writes a message to the console log when that happens to explain the problem.

Comment: Will get the info! Tho, the crash is inconsistent, I get it once a week or so... In my app I have several dussin of shaders that can be daisy chained in almost any order, so a lot of scenarios! So next time it happens I'll grab the console output and stack trace.